# Get the Last Date that an Item's Price Changed

Tags: c#, .net, class, data-structures

I have 3 columns, Stock, Price and Saved that come from a DB. We store the prices daily regardless of price change and I am trying to pull out the last date a price changed.

What I Tried:

- Using a foreach loop to iterate on inv and match the prices but I am getting lost somewhere along the lines.
- Using LINQ, I am getting the date of the last update to the database, not the last price update.
- Duplicating the list and comparing the arr[0] with arr2[1], when the numbers do not match print date.

Code:

```
namespace StackOverFlowQ2
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Data
        {
            public List<Inventory> myInv { get; set; }
        }

        public class Inventory
        {
            public string stock { get; set; }
            public string price { get; set; }
            public string saved { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inv = new List<Inventory>
            {
                new Inventory
                {
                    stock = "Apple",  price = "31", saved = "8/10/2019 12:01:01 AM"
                },
                new Inventory
                {
                    stock = "Apple",  price = "31", saved = "8/9/2019 12:01:01 AM"
                },
                new Inventory
                {
                    stock = "Apple",  price = "31", saved = "8/8/2019 12:01:01 AM"
                },
                new Inventory
                {
                    stock = "Apple",  price = "31", saved = "8/7/2019 12:01:01 AM"
                },
                new Inventory
                {
                    stock = "Apple",  price = "28", saved = "8/6/2019 12:01:01 AM"
                },
                new Inventory
                {
                    stock = "Apple",  price = "28", saved = "8/5/2019 12:01:01 AM"
                },
                new Inventory
                {
                    stock = "Apple", price = "28", saved = "8/4/2019 12:01:01 AM"
                }
            };

            #region Solution
            //Iterate through the List
            for (int i = 0; i < inv.Count - 1; i++)
            {   
                //Compare current index to next index
                if (inv[i].price != inv[i + 1].price)
                {   
                    //Print results                                   
                    Console.WriteLine(inv[i].saved);
                    break;
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Current Output: `8/10/2019 12:01:01 AM`

Expected Output: `8/7/2019 12:01:01 AM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!! :)

```
//Iterate through the List
for (int i = 0; i < inv.Count-1; i++)
{   
    //Compare current index to next index
    if (inv[i].price != inv[i + 1].price)
    {   
        //Print results                                   
        Console.WriteLine(inv[i].saved);
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
8/7/2019 12:01:01 AM
```

Comment: You're wasting iterations, it would be quicker to do this in reverse

Comment: What about adding ```break;``` after printing the results. Wouldn't that achieve the same thing? (Asking because it is what I did in my project and am curious about doing it in reverse now)

Comment: No, it wouldn't do the same this.  If you do it in reverse you'd  just be looking for the first change. Say you have 100 records and the 99th was the change you'd only have to iterate over 1 record instead of 99

Comment: Adding break would save some but not as much as reverse with a break

Comment: Ohh gotcha! That depends on how the data is ordered, the data from the DB is already sorted by save in descending order. Technically, I am starting at the end of the list already since it has the most recent in the front of the list rather than the end.

Comment: in that case you should definetly be using a break statement

Answer (score 1):

It would have been nice if `saved` was actually a `DateTime` but we can convert it whilst sorting.

```
var inStock = Model.MyInvData
    .OrderBy(x=>DateTime.ParseExact(x.saved, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: It would have been, but I have to work with what was provided to me lol. I got a System.FormatExeption: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Comment: Try with a single `M` as you don't have leading zeros on the month part.

Comment: No luck with the single month, the date string is holding ```10/2/2019 12:00:00 AM``` and I am using ```MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt``` for the second parameter. I even tried a single ```d```

Comment: I got your solution to work, so it orders the list by the save date and gets the last value. I am also trying to compare the price as well. That way I can get the last date the price changed, not the last date an item was entered in the database.

Comment: Technically this is Not correct, the OP stated that "I am trying to pull out the last date a price changed."  You are just getting the last date regardless of whether the price changed.